# Reinstall OS X on MacBook Pro with broken trackpad

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touchpad

I have to reinstall OS X on my MacBook Pro. I'm using the installation disk, but the only problem is that my trackpad is broken (I cannot click).

Is there any way to open and select the Utilities menu using the keyboard?

Comment: What version of OS X are you trying to install?

Comment: You could try pressing `Ctrl-F2` to focus the menu bar and navigate with arrow keys from there, or, if there's a help menu, press `Cmd-?` and type the name of the menu item you want to reach.

Comment: I tried Ctrl-F2 but it didn't work.... any other advice? version is Leopard.... I guess.....

Comment: I hate to ask, but connecting a USB mouse is not an option?

Comment: If you haven't tried it, maybe use `Fn-Ctrl-F2`?

Comment: thanks slhck.....that worked!!!....if you answer the question I'm gonna accept it.... thanks again!!!

Comment: FYI, `Fn+Brighter Screen` *is* `F2`. Just like in regular OS X. @slhck Pinging you.

Comment: @Daniel Go ahead and answer, you were right all along.. I just had a feeling ;)

Comment: I am having the same issue. Trackpad can move but not click, and I have tried 3 USB mouses but none work in either USB port on a 2011 macbook 13". I am trying to replace a dead hard drive, and was able to get into disk utility and format the drive, but now trying to select the hard drive for use with Install OS X and I can move with the arrows but have no way to hit 'Continue'. Tried spacebar, enter, tabbing, etc but nothing works!!! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To navigate the menu bar with the keyboard, you need to press `Ctrl-F2`. This will put the keyboard focus on the first menu bar item from which you can navigate to the desired menu item using the arrow keys.

By default, you need to press `Fn+F2` to actually get `F2`, since the key's default mode is the special function (increase brightness). So you need to press `Ctrl-Fn-F2` to actually focus the menu bar.